# Java library that has solutions for parsing forwarded emails from different major email clients

Tags: java, parsing, email, forward

I'm looking for a java library that has solutions for parsing forwarded emails from different major email clients. Could someone point me in a direction to find one or could someone share an example with me?

Comment: Do you already have a way of getting the emails?  What type of parsing will be required for the emails you're getting.  Is there a specific format that you need to parse (xml, html, plain text, etc.)?